# I can't make some Eloquent relations to work

Tags: laravel, database-design, model, eloquent, database-relations

Let me first explain the relations of my table, and then I will explain what I cannot do.

So, I have an entity called "Company" it has many "Incomes" which has many "IncomeUnitSale" which has one "IncomeUnitSaleUnitPrice"

```
Company 1->* Income 1->* IncomeUnitSale 1->1 IncomeUnitSaleUnitPrice
```

Models:

Company Model

```
public function Income(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Income');
}
```

Income Model (table has "company_id")

```
public function Company(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}

public function IncomeUnitSale(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\IncomeUnitSale');
}
```

IncomeUnitSale Model (table has "income_id")

```
public function Income(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Income');
}

public function IncomeUnitSaleUnitPrice(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\IncomeUnitSaleUnitPrice');
}
```

IncomeUnitSaleUnitPrice  (table has "income_unit_sale_id")

```
public function IncomeUnitSale(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\IncomeUnitSale');
}
```

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
$company = Company::where("id","=",1)->first();
$company->Income->IncomeUnitSale->IncomeUnitSaleUnitPrice
```

But It says its null, it works till `$company->Income->IncomeUnitSale` but after that doest't show any relation.

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasMany` relationships will always return an Eloquent `Collection` object. If there are no related records, it will just be an empty `Collection`. `hasOne` and `belongsTo` relationships will always return either the related Model, or `null` if there is no related model.

Because some of your relationships are `hasMany`, you have to iterate the returned `Collection` to be able to go further. So, instead of `$company->Income->IncomeUnitSale->IncomeUnitSaleUnitPrice`, you have to:

```
foreach($company->Income as $income) {
    foreach($income->IncomeUnitSale as $sale) {
        echo $sale->IncomeUnitSaleUnitPrice->price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It would be nicer to `$company->Income->IncomeUnitSale->IncomeUnitSaleUnitPrice` to be honest. But that worked too and well, thank you!

Comment: @mkmnstr If your company has multiple incomes and each income has multiple unit sale prices, which record would you expect `$company->Income->IncomeUnitSale->IncomeUnitSaleUnitPrice` to return?

Comment: Totally right. I don't know what I was thinking xD Thanks!